# How to stop Apache from listing the contents of my user directories

Tags: linux, security, apache, directory-listing

I recently ran some **penetration testing software** on my web site and was surprised for it to report that one of my directory listings was publicly accessible.

It is the directory of the root user which is available.

http://www.example.com/~root/

Results in this page content:

```
Index of /~root

    * Parent Directory
    * cgi-bin/
```

*Platform: I am creating PHP websites, with Symfony on Linux with Apache.*

**Is this something that I can configure through Apache?**

Comment: many distributions include a config file that exposes these userdirs. You can often just not include that config file. You may want to ask on serverfault for some more complete answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a `.htaccess` file in that directory, or have a `<directory>...</directory>` block in your Apache configuration that specifies:

```
Options -Indexes
```

See [the Apache options directive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#options) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command in Apache that will make it show indexes.

```
Options +Indexes
```

Remove this, restart. This will make that url show a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: So that's what Options +Indexes does! Thanks!