# Web Design Image Folder Access

Tags: php, sql, upload, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop Apache from listing the contents of my user directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845981/how-to-stop-apache-from-listing-the-contents-of-my-user-directories)

I am working on a blog and I successfully placed my uploaded image's filepath into an sql database. The images itself are stored inside the img folder. I want users to be able to retrieve their own image on their own blog page using a primary key and that WORKS.

On the other hand, if you go to my website followed with /img in the url, any users can publicly view all the other users' pictures.

Is there any way I can prevent anyone from messing with or publicly viewing my /img folder, while normal users who are logged in can still retrieve their own picture on their own blog page via the sql filepath process?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the files under the public folder, meaning on the root and then call them with a php wrapper depending on their id. something like : `<img src="img/img.php?id=ac34" />` in your img.php you output the image with image headers if the user has the rights to view it. In your database table , you have the real image path that corresponds to your ac34 token, and this is what your img.php loads and outputs as image to the requester. This way the real path of your server files stays hidden and you get to check access rights for every image load.

Answer (score 0):

Create `.htaccess` file and add:

```
Options -Indexes
```

It will block all indexing from all folders.